# Free software that converts .zip to .exe?

Tags: media-converter

Is there any free software/app/website that converts .zip files to .exe files?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What do you expect the .exe to do? Extract the .zip? ie. self extracting exe?

Comment: If you just mean a self-extracting archive then *most* **good** archivers do support that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [PeaZip](http://peazip.sourceforge.net/):

- free and open source
- cross-platform
- allow to create [self-extracting archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-extracting_archive)

Other tools:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-extracting_archive :

> Several programs can create self-extracting archives. For Windows
>   there are WinZip, WinRAR, 7-Zip, WinUHA, KGB Archiver, the built-in
>   IExpress wizard and many other experimental ones. For Macintosh there
>   are StuffIt, The Unarchiver, and 7zX.